# css display inline and float not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following very simple layout:[Inline search and logout button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfsAh.png)

As you can see I have a problem with displaying these inline. here is the code:

html:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<div class="search">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search here..." required>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="logout">
    <a href="logout.php" class="button-small">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar
{
display: inline-block;
background: #607D8B;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
width: 100%;
height:27px;
}

.search {
background-color: chartreuse;
width: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.logout {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
}

.logout,
.username
{
background-color: chartreuse;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.logout a,
.header-heading a
{
/*display: block;*/
padding: .7em 1em;
color: #607D8B;
text-decoration:none;
/*border-bottom: 1px solid gray;*/
font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
}

.logout a:link { color: #607D8B; }

.logout a:visited { color: #607D8B; }

.logout a:focus
{
color: #607D8B;
font-weight:bolder;
}

.logout a:hover
{
color: #607D8B;
font-weight:bolder;
}

.logout a:active
{
color: #607D8B;
}
```

I`ve tried all I can but for some reason the se are still being displayed as shown in the image attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not aligned as you *forget* to add `display: inline-block` to `.search`
Making it inline-block will horizontally align it with other inline or inline-block elements.

Also you don't need `margin: 0 auto;` anymore. To position it use other techniques.

I've created a fiddle with your code [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mm2tfnh5/)

**UPDATE**

`.nav-bar` should not have `display: inline-block` property.
It has to stay as block to be full-width container for your search form and button.

You can stick to your previous solution for centering the `.search`

To position logout button on the right top, use `position: absolute;`

```
.logout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px; //As padding-top of  .nav-bar
  ...
 }
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mm2tfnh5/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this solved one problem. may I ask what would you suggest which techniques I use to center the search bar?

Comment: I'll update my answer in a moment, but I suggest you to read more about CSS positioning, display property and box-model – due to your code you might misunderstand it in some parts

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to get everything to line-up in the header - try using absolute-positioning on the .logout DIV. e.g. [here](https://zornfett.bitbucket.io/stack-42122108/) .. in the event you want the 'logout' button positioned near the bottom of the header as in the screen capture, then just increase the value of the 'top' positioning.